# Maui editor text_changed event weird behavior

Tags: editor, maui, textchanged

So here is my editor text changed event:

```
 private void FormulaEditor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!changedByControls)
        {
            int oldTextLength = e.OldTextValue?.Length ?? 0;
            int newTextLength = e.NewTextValue?.Length ?? 0;           

            bool textInserted = newTextLength > oldTextLength;

            TextAction action = textInserted ? TextAction.Insert : TextAction.Remove;
            int textLength = Math.Abs(newTextLength - oldTextLength);
            int startIndex = textInserted ? FormulaEditor.CursorPosition : FormulaEditor.CursorPosition - textLength;

            string textForOperation = textInserted ? e.NewTextValue: e.OldTextValue;
            string text = textForOperation.Substring(startIndex, textLength);

            textCommandManager.ChangeText(action, text, startIndex);
            UndoButton.IsEnabled = textCommandManager.CanUndo;
        }
        
        changedByControls = false;         
    }
```

I will explain what happens here. Every time when I insert or remove a symbol or some part of text, this text is added to the commands list with appropriate action. When I insert a symbol or text, everything works correctly. When I delete one character or text completely everything also works fine. But when I select a part of a word and delete it, for example, I encounter very strange behavior. Let me explain with an example. Let's say I copied and pasted the word "wasabi" into my editor. At the moment, the list of commands contains one element and looks like this:

```
indexOfElement - 0, action - Insert, Position - 0, Text - "wasabi".
```

Now, for example, I have selected a part of the word "sabi" and clicked delete. I noticed that in this case, the TextChangedEvent is always triggered 3 times and then contains 4 elements (given that the first element was the word "wasabi" inserted at the beginning). After deleting this part of the word, the list looks like this:

```
indexOfElement - 0, action - Insert, Position - 0, Text - "wasabi";
indexOfElement - 1, action - Remove, Position - 2, Text - "sabi" (this is the value I expected, but unfortunately it is followed by 2 more elements); 
indexOfElement - 2, action - Remove, Position - 0, Text - "wa"; 
indexOfElement - 3, action - Insert, Position - 0, Text - "wa";
```

Can anyone explain what this behavior is due to and how to fix it?

Comment: what is `textCommandManager`? I have not seen that before.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it’s my implementation of command pattern. It’s just adding command to list and executing it

Comment: If your question is about calls made to textchanged, then add debug print statement (at start of textchanged) showing the parameters received by textchanged. When debugging, simplify the situation as much as possible. Showing the output of other methods instead, just complicates the situation.

Comment: Did the `textCommandManager.ChangeText` will trigger the textchanged event?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT no, it’s not

Comment: But I can't be sure because when I try to debug this event, I get a message that incompatible code is running in the thread. But there is no code that can trigger this event

Comment: I found out that this strange behavior occurs when, as I said earlier, only a part of the word is deleted, not the entire word. I also noticed that if I delete 2 words at once, for example, "good job". Then if I delete only the word job, I get this strange behavior again, but if I delete the word job with a space like this "job", then everything works as intended.

Comment: Did this problem appear on all the platforms?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I also test on windows. There all working like I expected

Comment: So the probem appeared on the android and ios? Did you test on the emulator or the physical device?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT on emulator

Comment: You can try to test on the physical device and I can't reproduce your problem because your code is not completed.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT i post my answer, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the visual studio update just worked for me. I read about this bug with the inability to debug earlier on github, maybe now it's just fixed. Or maybe it was just that some library was damaged or something else. In short, everything works fine now, the method behavior is as expected, the text changed event can now also be debugged (I couldn't do it before, I got a message that incompatible code was running in the thread). Thanks to everyone who tried to solve my problem